# New boost::thread causes object destructor to be called many times more than expected?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, destructor

Strange behavior from the code posted below causes the objects destructor to be called more than once. While the code doesn't crash as a result I just want to find out why such behavior occurs. It's a very simple template of a normal program probably used by many people all around Boost land but I've never noticed this behavior till now.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class object
{
    private:

        int value;

    public:

    object();
    ~object();
    void pass( int value);
};

object::object()
{
    std::cout<<"constructing object: "<<this<<" with value: "<<this->object::value<<std::endl;
}
object::~object()
{
    std::cout<<"destructing  object: "<<this<<" with value: "<<this->object::value<<std::endl;
}
void object::pass( int value)
{
    this->object::value = value;
    std::cout<<"value passed is: "<<this->object::value<<std::endl;
}

class threaded
{
    private:

         object A;

    public:

    threaded();
    ~threaded();
    void init( int value);
};
threaded::threaded(){}
threaded::~threaded(){}
void threaded::init( int value)
{
    this->threaded::A.pass( value);
}

int main()
{
    threaded T;
    int unlucky_number = 13;

    boost::thread_group tg;

    tg.add_thread( new boost::thread( boost::bind( &threaded::init, T, unlucky_number)));

    tg.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the code output.

```
constructing object: 0x7ffcb53157f0 with value: 0

destructing  object: 0x7ffcb53156d0 with value: 0 <----From here?
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb5315720 with value: 0
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb53157a0 with value: 0
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb5315780 with value: 0
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb5315710 with value: 0
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb53157c0 with value: 0
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb5315820 with value: 0
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb5315800 with value: 0 <----To here?

value passed is: 13
destructing  object: 0x1a5f2d8 with value: 13
destructing  object: 0x7ffcb53157f0 with value: 0
```

The objects destroyed after the first one constructed and the before the line **`value passed is: 13`** must have somehow been created by a copy constructor inside the boost thread library but why were they never constructed and why no crash? Plus their values are always zero so it's not junk memory... any ideas?

So at the request of G.M. I tried to create copy constructors only to get boost related errors in the error_code.hpp.

Here's the new code plus the errors compiling it.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class object
{
    private:

        int value;

    public:

    object();
    object( object const &copy_this);
    ~object();
    void pass( int value);
};

object::object()
{
    std::cout<<"constructing object: "<<this<<" with value: "<<this->object::value<<std::endl;
}
object::object( object const &copy_this)
{
    std::cout<<"object copy constructor. "<<std::endl;
    this->object::value = copy_this.value;
}
object::~object()
{
    std::cout<<"destructing  object: "<<this<<" with value: "<<this->object::value<<std::endl;
}
void object::pass( int value)
{
    this->object::value = value;
    std::cout<<"value passed is: "<<this->object::value<<std::endl;
}

class threaded
{
    private:

         object A;

    public:

    threaded();
    threaded( threaded const &copy_this);
    ~threaded();
    void init( int value);
};
threaded::threaded(){}
threaded::threaded( threaded const &copy_this)
{
    std::cout<<"threaded copy constructor. "<<std::endl;
    this->threaded::A = copy_this.A;
}
threaded::~threaded(){}
void threaded::init( int value)
{
    this->threaded::A.pass( value);
}

int main()
{
    threaded T;
    int unlucky_number = 13;

    boost::thread_group tg;

    tg.add_thread( new boost::thread( boost::bind( &threaded::init, T, unlucky_number)));

    tg.join_all();
    //T.init(13);

    return 0;
}

||=== Build: Debug in boost_thread_destructor_problem (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|221|undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|222|undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|223|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp|51|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::condition_error::condition_error(int, char const*)':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp|84|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp|152|undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(pthread_mutex_t*, pthread_cond_t*)':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp|195|undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|179|undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::thread::~thread()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|254|undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::thread::get_id() const':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|741|undefined reference to `boost::thread::native_handle()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::thread::join()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|767|undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp|84|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::shared_mutex::lock_shared()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp|186|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp|186|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp|186|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::shared_mutex::lock()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp|287|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()'|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp|287|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'|
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp|287|undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::~disable_interruption()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::thread_group::join_all()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread_group.hpp|117|undefined reference to `boost::thread::joinable() const'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, threaded, int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<threaded>, boost::_bi::value<int> > > >::thread_data(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, threaded, int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<threaded>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >)':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|109|undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o||In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, threaded, int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<threaded>, boost::_bi::value<int> > > >::~thread_data()':|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|90|undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'|
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp|90|undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'|
obj/Debug/boost_thread_destructor_problem.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf1Iv8threadediEENS2_5list2INS2_5valueIS6_EENS9_IiEEEEEEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf1Iv8threadediEENS2_5list2INS2_5valueIS6_EENS9_IiEEEEEEEE]+0x10)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 24 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Implement your own copy constructor for both `object` and `threaded` with suitable logging and check the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way you've invoked [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_pointers_to_memb)...

```
tg.add_thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&threaded::init, T, unlucky_number)));
```

`T` will be passed by value.  That can lead to any amount of copying of `T` being performed by the `boost::bind` implementation.

Since you know that `T` will, in this case, outlive the thread on which it's being used you can either force a pass by reference...

```
tg.add_thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&threaded::init, boost::ref(T), unlucky_number)));
```

or pass a pointer...

```
tg.add_thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&threaded::init, &T, unlucky_number)));
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions, I'm still trying to get the copy constructors to work. I'll post as soon as that happens.

Comment: Beware. Passing by value is very good practice in the threaded world. It will insulate you from the bulk of race conditions and, indeed, lifetime requirements (dangling reference)

Comment: Are you sure passing by value is a good practice, maybe you meant something else. I've heard something about boost pointers being useful, what about those @sehe

Comment: I said: in the context of threading. Reason is that threading becomes complicated (and very error-prone) with shared data (references easily lead to that) and lifetime mismatches (references easily lead to that).

Comment: "Boost pointers" do not exist. You probably mean smart pointers. They don't really change anything, except making ownership more explicit and perhaps enabling light-weight passing of non-movable or non-copyable types.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant smart pointers. I updated the code with copy constructors but it's full of errors now. Not a problem. I'll just try G.M.'s way and yours.

Comment: Sorry, was away for a while but.. just to echo what @sehe said: pass by value is the default because it's essentially the fail-safe option -- it copies everything up into a nice self contained callable object.

Answer (score 3):

You can alleviate much of this by avoiding `bind`. Lambdas solve this issue - most often more efficiently:

[C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/827921b39547612f)

```
tg.create_thread([=]() mutable { T.init(unlucky_number); });
```

In C++14 you [can be a bit more advanced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d405f3ce6b844040):

```
tg.create_thread([T=std::move(T), unlucky_number = 13]() mutable { T.init(unlucky_number); });
```

If `object` is expensive to copy, consider making it move-aware, e.g.

```
object(object const&)       = default;
object(object&&)            = default;
object& operator=(object&&) = default;
```

To ensure the compiler generates the special members even though you added user-declared (non-trivial) constructor/destructor members.